# Make two blocks side by side of same size

Tags: html, css, height, responsive

I'm having issues for something that should be simple but that is not.
I want to do that :
[image: my goal]

I want these two red block having the same height, while their content will be of kinda unpredictable height.
Usually people are advised to use a table, except that then the border and margin of these red block becomes a problem, since I want a space to exist between the blocks but not on left and right (common problem if I'm correct).
I've tried to put a negative margin as I've seen around but it didn't workout.

I ended up giving up tables and trying to simulate a margin / padding / border with outline and background-clip, then background-offset but it didn't perfectly work, plus imho I shouldn't have to do that for something that simple.

I tried to do things with fixed height, so the red block could be set height: 100%, which is not that bad with media queries to make it responsive, but since I don't know the size of content for sure : I end up having either overflow or too big padding on bottom.

As a detail : I want to avoid flexbox (with grow) since it's not always very compatible, and javascript, because it's a css issue, so it's pretty bad to fix it that way.

Any ideas ? Thanks a lot

Comment: Flexbox is the way to go for this, and as long as it is something this basic, there shouldn’t be any significant compatibility issues in any currently relevant browsers either.

Comment: I'm afraid there is, flex grow tends to go back on IE, I've seen cases where a simple display: flex; make a big mess on firefox (v 38 if I'm correct)

Answer (score 1):

Is something like this a solution for you? But I do suggest that you use `flex-grow`, support is pretty good.

```css
.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.col {
  padding: 2rem;
  width: 200px;
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: red;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sodales et quam vel fermentum. Maecenas scelerisque mauris quis orci convallis pretium.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla sodales et quam vel fermentum. Maecenas scelerisque mauris quis orci convallis pretium. Duis scelerisque magna egestas efficitur fermentum. Aenean varius vitae ipsum at rutrum. Quisque at convallis odio, ac ullamcorper arcu. Praesent dignissim ornare tortor, et fringilla arcu.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're going to need a gutter column to achieve the space between the blocks as required by the question.

Comment: The gutter is what I should have done when I used tables... If I give flexbox up I'm definitely gonna do that.

Answer (score 1):

Well after a few tried and your suggestions, my result is:
I tried display grid that was perfect on chrome but shameful on IE 11 (yes I've put the prefixes, it didn't changes anything. (I used display: grid and grid-template-columns: 30% 70%; which is supposed to work...)

Then tried display: flex (I didn't even need flex-grow, but I've put prefixes) and it worked, even on IE.

So I chose flexbox.

Comment: Nice to hear that you managed to solve it. Whenever you find yourself wondering if something is going to work in old browsers, check out https://caniuse.com/

Comment: I did but apparently it was lying :/

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to achieve this result with `display: grid` ([read more](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)). The same effect can be achieved with other properties like `flexbox` ([read more](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)).

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  padding: 15px;
}
.container div {
  background: tomato;
  border: 2px solid #aaa;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum.</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, it doesn't work (I clicked on run snippet)

Comment: display grid seem to work pretty well, if you make an answer with it, I'll validate it

Comment: actuallt it doesn't work at all of IE 11, not even with prefixes, I don't get it....

Comment: updated, it is using grid now. sorry for the wrong code.

Comment: Working now ! But not at all of IE 11 so not really suitable :/